# I am trying to insert total of 4 subjects and their average in database from asp.net, its showing successfully added but not actually adding

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to develop a web application which can add 4 subjects and average them and save it to database,. All things are correct still i am facing a problem. I tried many solutions but not working
After executing the web application i insert all the elements as required and even it shows up "1 record successfully added" but in actually its not adding in database. So can anyone help me out ?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgJWQ.jpg)

Comment: Put some Windex on it. If that doesn't work, try to sacrifice a goat. If even that doesn't work, then perhaps you should, oh, I don't know, show us your code, maybe?

Comment: @Rishav : You are not executing the query. Use **`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`**.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgJWQ.jpg

Comment: @Wanderer You are correct, i had forgotten to add cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Thank you So much.. @Wanderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the **`ExecuteNonQuery()`** to execute the query for inserting the row into the database table.

**[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)**

You must add the below line to your click event after parameter passing part.

**code**

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, it returns the number of rows affected.

```
int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```